# Is Adobe flex 4.1 compatible with flash player 13.0.0.214

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Currently we are running Flash Player 10.1.85.3 with Adobe Flex 4.1.  I cannot find any information that speaks to Flex 4.1 working with newer versions of Flash.  In particular I'd like to know if anyone has confirmed that these two pair or do not.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/downloads_updaters.html

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any official compatibility statement for Adobe Flex 4.1 and Flash Player 13, but I think you could assume that the following [compatibility statement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff9.html) also applies for Version 13 and newer Versions:

> As always, Flash Player provides full backward compatibility with
>   previously published content.

I never had problems with newer versions of Flash Player and older SDKs. So typically your application requires a minimum Flash Player version and not a maximum.